# People Search Performance Issue

Tags: search, performance

We are running SP2013 and only recently developed a very basic intranet. One web app, one site collection, three sites.

We have configured People Search and it has been importing AD user data and running fine until about a week ago. Now page loading can take over a minute. Most of the time it just doesn't load but time's out with the usual unhelpful SharePoint error message, 'something went wrong'. Occassionally, it does render the page and then the search works - but it is slow in returning results.

I've checked services, all seem ok. I've rebooted the app and web server.

I am seeing an error message in the event log:

> A certificate validation operation took 13702.4966 milliseconds and has exceeded the execution time threshold.  If this continues to
>   occur, it may represent a configuration issue.

I went to the MS site but to be honest it could have been written in Latin for the help it provided.

Has anyone elswe experienced this problem? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your SharePoint root certificate has trust validation issues. You can try to export that certificate and then import it into the trusted certificates store on each SharePoint server.

More details can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2625048

Comment: Thanks for this - I've installed the certificate on both web and app server successfully now and the error message no longer appears in the app event log. 
However, this has had no effect on our performance issue.
Every other page I navigate to from the home page is rendered in less than 1 second. The People Search page takes for ever (+1 minute) and only renders occassionally.

Comment: I suppose the "normal" search results appear ok? It's only the people search results, right?